# Expression or idiom: disappointment

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Is there an expression that you could use when you feel really disappointed because no one appreciates your favor and kindness, and they usually upset or hurt you instead. An expression that suggests this usually happens to you (Not 'bite the hand that feeds you')

Comment: It sounds like you're feeling **unappreciated**.

Comment: You suffer from ingratitude.

Comment: You suffer from teenage daughters.

Comment: Speaking figuratively, you might say that you feel as if you're being "treated like a stepping stone."

Answer (score 4):

“No good deed goes unpunished”

(No clear origin for this phrase at
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_good_deed_goes_unpunished))

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're feeling [unappreciated](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1#q=define%3A%20unappreciated):

> not fully understood, recognized, or valued.
>
> "she had been brought up in a family where she felt unappreciated and undervalued"
>
> synonyms: unacknowledged, unthanked, uncredited, unrecognized, taken for granted, overlooked; undervalued, underpaid

Answer (score 1):

You might say you're...

> [**crestfallen**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crestfallen) (Merriam-Webster)
>    adjective
>    *dejected; dispirited; discouraged.*

Note that this usage often (but not always) has connotations of *shame*.

Answer (score 1):

You could say, *you're **too** kind/nice/helpful **for your own good***.

> *Are you agreeable, accommodating, and saintly to a fault? Being too nice to your own good can take a toll on you. The key: knowing when to curtail kindness*. [Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/collections/201203/too-nice-your-own-good